# get specific KBs installed on remote servers

Tags: powershell

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCEJv.jpg)Trying to run the following powershell script in order to find the kbs from a list, installed on remote severs, from a list as well.

```
$computers = gc C:\users\xxx\Desktop\powershell\computers.txt
$patches = gc C:\users\xxx\Desktop\powershell\patch.txt
$credentials = Get-Credential
 

 foreach ($patch in $patches){
 
 Get-HotFix -id $patch -ComputerName $computers -OutVariable results -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Credential $credentials
 
 if ($results -ne $null) {
 
 $results | Out-File C:\users\xxx\Desktop\powershell\result.txt -Append -Force
 
 }
 
 else {
 
 Add-content "$computer missing $Patch" -path "mypath\missing.txt"
 
 }
 
 }
```

and getting the following error:

```
Get-HotFix : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the 
command again.
At line:8 char:38
+  Get-HotFix -id $patch -ComputerName $computers -OutVariable results  ...
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-HotFix], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHotFixCommand
```

Comment: Maybe `$computers` has nothing in it.

Comment: $computers contains the list of computers where I am trying to get the info from.
there is a list as follows:
computer1
computer2
etc

Comment: Not according to the error.

Comment: @DougMaurer I can see that...my question is...is my formatting wrong for the computers file?

Comment: If `C:\users\xxx\Desktop\powershell\computers.txt` is an actual file that contains computer names, one per line, and your account has access to it, then your code ***should*** not produce this error. If `gc` is something other than an alias for `Get-Content` in your session, you may have undesired results too.

Comment: have moved to a different location and used the solution proposed by Abraham Zinala and it is working now. 
Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does this do?

```
$computers = gc C:\users\xxx\Desktop\powershell\computers.txt
$patches = gc C:\users\xxx\Desktop\powershell\patch.txt
$credentials = Get-Credential
 
Foreach($Computer in $computers){
        foreach ($patch in $patches){
 
 Get-HotFix -id $patch -ComputerName $Computer -OutVariable results -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Credential $credentials
 
 if ($results -ne $null) {
 
 $results | Out-File C:\users\xxx\Desktop\powershell\result.txt -Append -Force
 
 }
 
 else {
 
 Add-content "$computer missing $Patch" -path "mypath\missing.txt"
        }
    }
 
 }
```

Comment: This seems to be getting the info I needed, but for some reason, I am getting the following error:
```
Get-HotFix : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At C:\powershell\find_missing_patches.ps1:8 char:2
+  Get-HotFix -id $patch -ComputerName $Computer -OutVariable results - ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-HotFix], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHotFixCommand
```

Comment: are all your systems online? It seems that its having issues connecting to some to retrieve the info. If they are online, you may want to ensure winrm is running

Comment: it seems like for every server is prompting the error, but in the same time, getting the info  I need...
Thanks again for your help!